# Storing incremental changes in Azure postgresql database from prod server database

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, cdc, wal, azure-postgresql

Background : I have my prod postgresql db on a remote server and another DB some other azure server.
2nd db has been restored with the full backup of prod db. I need to transfer all the latest changes in the 2nd DB which is on some other server.
As of now I create complete backup of the prod db and drop and create the 2nd db and restore it with the prod db backup using pg_restore command.
What I want is to not drop the 2nd db but to just run the incremental changes.

My thoughts : I found that I can use the WAL files from prod db to simply run them on 2nd db. But I couldn't find any implementation for that.
I am able to Archive those WAL files in some other directory but couldn't find a way to do the next steps.

1. Can anyone guide me how to run those WAL files on some other server?
2. Is there any other way to just add the incremental changes and not the whole db?
3. Any open source tool which I can use?

Any suggestion or thoughts will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.